How to convert MutableState<String> to Int
I'm trying to convert a MutableState(String) to Int in the Jetpack compose screen as below:
val secondScreenResult = navHostController.currentBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle
    ?.getLiveData<String>("selectedPosition")?.observeAsState()

secondScreenResult?.value?.let {
    // Read the result
    val pos = it.toInt()
}

But it always throws below error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MutableState(value=1)@196947123"

Any idea how to fix it?

Maybe this snippet will work for you, because from the error it looks like you didn't get the value of the MutableState correctly
val secondScreenResult = navHostController.currentBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle
    ?.getLiveData<String>("selectedPosition")?.observeAsState()

 secondScreenResult?.value?.let {
        // Read the result
        val pos = it.value.toInt()
    }



The string you want to convert does not contain "1", it contains "MutableState(value=1)@196947123". This cannot be converted into an Int hence the NumberFormatException.
The problem is not the String-to-Int-conversion, it is how you save the Int in the first place. You didn't show us that code but from what it looks like you probably start out with a mutable state. Let's assume it to be this:
val state = mutableStateOf(1)

You then convert that to a String, either explicitly like state.toString() or using a string template like this "$state". Both will produce a String simiar to "MutableState(value=1)@196947123".
What you want instead is to only convert the value of the state, either by  state.value.toString() or "${state.value}". This will produce the String "1". And that can then be converted back to an Int with the code you already have.
